# A big different of initial loss (iteration=0) between choosing of weight initialization. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I have 128 feature map with size 32x32. I want to upsampling/deconvolution it to 8x256x256, where `8` is the number of feature map output. I used `Deconvolution` layer in CAFFE for doing the task.

```
layer {
  name: "Deconvolution1"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "layer1"
  top: "Deconvolution1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    bias_term: false
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 8
    stride: 8
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
  }
}
```

In my setting, I used weight_filter is `msra`, because I trained my network from scratch. I also tried with other filter, like `gaussian` with std=0.01. The results show a big different at initial loss. With `msra`, my initial loss is 6.5, while with gaussian is 1.2. Has something wrong? My expected loss at initial is less than 2. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

The initial loss is immaterial.  Yes, a difference random spread can change it significantly.  I see a 20% difference often enough, using the *same* initial filter in a benchmark topology (vis. AlexNet).

The question is how well the model trains.  If your loss drops to expected ranges within an epoch or two, and continues a general downward trend until convergence, then you have a viable approach.